# Does the payoff in a future option contract include the price of the future contract?

Tags: mathematical-economics, asset-pricing, financial-derivatives

[This](https://analystprep.com/blog/options-calculations-payoff-profit/) website has this diagram
[image]

which shows the payoff as $0$ for $S_T\leq X$ or $S_T\geq X$ (depending on the position-option combination). But isn't the buyer/seller of the position down/up the future price $c$ of the option agreed in the future contract? Shouldn't the payoff be $\pm c$ for the regions shown as $0$?

Comment: Hi: you pay at the beginning so the cost of the call or put is kind of viewed as a sunk cost.